# How to parse a zipped file with multiprocessing?

Tags: python

I have a huge zip file with a large number of files. Parsing all these files takes a lot of time, so I thought about using multiprocessing to speed things up. I am not sure how to approach it, as a zipfile.ZipFile in Python is not an iterable.

I am aware that I could extract all contents from the zip file and then iterate over the list of filenames, however, I'd prefer to not have to keep extra free space to hold the extracted data and would like to operate on the ZipFile.

Maybe there is any other solution to this this problem, so I am open to suggestions.

EDIT:
Using the below code technically works, but the problem is that each time the get_content() function runs, it seems the large zip file that I have is being opened again, ultimately taking as long as 15 seconds to reach each file.

```
import multiprocessing
from zipfile import ZipFile
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

path = 'zipfile.zip'

def get_file_list(zip_path):
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zipObj:
        listOfiles = zipObj.namelist()
    return listOfiles

def get_content(file_name):
    start_time = time.time()
    with ZipFile(path, 'r') as zipObject:
        with zipObject.open(file_name) as file:
            content = file.read()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"It took {end_time - start_time} to open this file")
    return content

def parse_files():
        file_list = get_file_list(path)
        with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
            contents = p.map(get_content, file_list)
        print(contents)

parse_files()
```

Comment: What's in your zipfile? What are you trying to parse out of it? What have you tried so far? Where's your code?

Comment: I'm not sure you're optimizing on the right thing here.  You either extract the list of files once and pass that to the subprocesses, or you re-extract the list over and over again in each subprocess.

Comment: @TimRoberts I extract the list of files once, but then, how do I manage to pass both that list of file names and the zip archive to the subprocesses? If I do not pass the ZipFile object to the subprocesses, then each time a file is read, the archive is being opened each time an iteration is being ran, which is taking a lot of time.

Comment: So, you store the list in a global. before you spawn the other processes.  They don't SHARE the memory, but the processes will inherit whatever globals you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile
from multiprocessing import Pool

def create_dummy_zip():
    os.mkdir("dummy")
    for i in range(100):
        with open(f"dummy/{i}.file", "w") as f:
            f.write(f"Content: {i}")
    shutil.make_archive("dummy", 'zip', "dummy")
    shutil.rmtree('dummy')

def delete_dummy():
    try:
        os.remove("dummy.zip")
        shutil.rmtree('dummy')
    except:
        pass
    
def get_file_list(zip_path):
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zipObj:
        listOfiles = zipObj.namelist()
    return listOfiles

def get_content(file_name):
    with ZipFile("dummy.zip", 'r') as zipObject:
        with zipObject.open(file_name) as file:
            content = file.read()
    return content
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        create_dummy_zip()
        file_list = get_file_list("dummy.zip")
        with Pool(5) as p:
            contents = p.map(get_content, file_list)
        print(contents)
        delete_dummy()
    except:
        delete_dummy()
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to multiprocessing, would you mind sharing how exactly would you apply it in this case?

Comment: lucky i have a good day :D

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the zip file that I have is fairly large (~1GB). Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't this line: with ZipFile("dummy.zip", 'r') as zipObject in the get_content function load the zip file every time the function is ran instead just once at the beginning? I tried running this against my data and it takes c. 15 seconds to read each file in the zip file, while without multiprocessing, when I am opening the zip file only once, each file is read in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Absolutly right. This code is far from optimized! It is a meer example of how the multiprocessing works. I would check if the zip context can be handed to multiple processes in parallel and instead of handing a single filename, I would split the list in sublists for each process